# Identifier 'required' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I need to declare this variable to type any? This shows up in my visual code editor in my HTML template.

[image]

product-form.component.html

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                Title is required.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input #price="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control" required [min]="0">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option *ngFor="let category of categories$ | async" [value]="category.key">{{ category.payload.val().name }}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
                  Category is required.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel" ngModel [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control" required url>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image URL is required.</div>
                  <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Please enter a valid URL.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

          </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" *ngIf="product.imageUrl">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'USD': symbol }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

product-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  categories$;
  product: any = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.productService.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
    }
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How do I remove this error? Functionality in the app doesn't seem to be effected. So from what I understand it compiles into valid JS. I was able to fix the objects by declaring it as "any"

I would be interested in learning how to setup an interface for this if possible.

Comment: Nowhere do we see what you have tried other than `any`. Also would be great if you could create a stackblitz that showcases this error :)

Answer (score 39):

There is a bug in angular. That compiler error will dissapear if you write that *ngIf like this:

```
          <div *ngIf="price.errors['required']">
```

Answer (score 27):

try to add "?" after "price".

Like this:

```
<div *ngIf="price?.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
<div *ngIf="price?.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
```

Comment: worked for me. Just so I understand what it does:  does it check if object is not null before accessing properties?

Answer (score 13):

I had same problem with my VS Code. I solved it only using `!!` before the condition.

Try:

```html
    <div *ngIf="!!price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
    <div *ngIf="!!price.errors.min">Price should be 0 or higher.</div>
```

More info: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/126

Comment: very nice answer thanks,  I have the same issue with !!name?.errors?.maxlength where maxlength show Identifier 'maxlength ' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member into VS Code. after runing the code with issue on browser it is not showing any error but the maxlength does not work means : p class="form-control-feedback-text"  *ngIf="name.errors?.maxlength && ( name.dirty || name.touched)">Name can not be more than 50 characters.</p> when i use !! then its work "What is the  issue is it TS or any other issue".

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid">
     <div *ngIf="email.errors['required']">Email is required</div>
     <div *ngIf="email.errors['minlength']">Email should be minimum {{ email.errors['minlength']['requiredLength'] }} characters</div>
     <div *ngIf="email.errors['maxlength']">Email should be maximum {{ email.errors['maxlength']['requiredLength'] }} characters</div>
     <div *ngIf="email.errors['pattern']">Email doesn't match the pattern.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Had similar error trying to access `FormArray` controls inside the `FormGroup` on the view using `ngFor`.

Some answers to this question worked partially, causing either compile errors or project build failure. For instance:

```
libraryForm.get('books') //compile error
libraryForm.controls['books'].controls' //build failure
```

Only below solution works for me so far:

`libraryForm['controls']['books']['controls']`

whole element:

```
<div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let book of libraryForm['controls']['books']['controls'];let i = index">
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my life! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `hasError()` method instead of `errors` property fixes it for me.
Use it like this:

```html
 <div *ngIf="price.hasError('required')">Price is required.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just **Add Question mark in-front of your property**

```
  <label [attr.data-error]="Password.errors!=null?(Password?.errors.Required?'Required 
  field!':'Minimum 3 Characters Needed'):''">Password</label>
```

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram   Yeah Sure...My pleasure..... It represent nullable property as first time it may null so that you have to handle it in such a way.....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, y solved thanks to the answer from António César Júnior:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403416/8992452
 by only using

```
   !!

<div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors">
    <p *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Email is required</p>
    <p *ngIf="f.username.errors.email">The mail address is invalid</p>
</div>
```

working in a previous project, then changed to:

```
 <div *ngIf="submitted && !!f.username.errors">
   <p *ngIf="!!f.username.errors.required">Email is required</p>
   <p *ngIf="!!f.username.errors.email">The mail address is invalid</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this solution (for me works fine)!

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid">
  <div *ngIf="username.errors['required']">Username are required!</div>
  <div *ngIf="username.errors['minlength']">Username should be minimum {{ username.errors['minlength'].requiredLength }} characters!</div>
  <div *ngIf="username.errors['cannotContainSpace']">Username cannot contains spaces!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be some issue mentioned in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators):

> Sometimes a binding expression triggers a type error during AOT compilation and it is not possible or difficult to fully specify the type. To silence the error, you can use the $any() cast function to cast the expression to the any type as in the following example

So you could do:

`$any(price.errors).required`